# How to open an unpublished post (draft) on a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I've created a new post using the graph API's "post" method. The API response is the post's ID:

```
{"id":"<postid>"}
```

Now I want to enable my app's user to open Facebook and edit or publish the post. I can link to the (unpublished post) using the url

```
https://www.facebook.com/<page>/posts/<postid>
```

but when the user opens this link, she gets a page displaying the post - without any publishing tools. (Mainly, no "publish" button

[image: Screenshot: FB post view page without publishing tools]

I could link to the page's publishing tools using the link

```
https://www.facebook.com/<page>/publishing_tools/?section=draft_posts
```

Alas, it opens a list of all unpublished posts and the user needs to open the one I just created manually.

[image: Publishing tools screenshot]

Any method of directly opening the publishing tools on a specific draft? Or opening the draft with a "Publish" button?

Comment: I would also love this, but I'm not sure that it is currently possible. In our application, we link to both the publishing tools and the post.